# how does this select_related work in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-select-related

I saw this example from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) on how to use `select_related()`:

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    hometown = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Then a call to `Book.objects.select_related('person', 'person__city').get(id=4)` will cache the related `Person` and the related `City`.

I do not understand the exact `query` that is made here. I understand the `query` `result` is pre-populated. but what  `query` ( in english or `sql` terms) is made here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned it pre-populates the `querySet`. That is, when the record is retrieved, it hits the `database` only once. If you do not have `select_related`, you will be making `database`calls to `Book,Person and City` individually, increasing the number of calls made from 1 to 3.

Comment: but is the exact query made in simple English is better?

Comment: I am accepting although it is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To show the exact query it will do, use this in the shell:

```
print Book.objects.select_related('person', 'person__city').get(id=4).query
```